# polynomial equation $ A(x+y_1)(x+y_2)...(x+y_n) + B(x+z_1)(x+z_2)...(x+z_k) = f(x) $ ??

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, factoring, vieta-jumping

Consider given integers $A,B$ such that $AB \neq 0$.

Consider a given polynomial $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ... $ of degree $n > 1$ with rational coefficients $a_i$.

Now I wonder about solving the diophantine equations of type :

$$ A(x+y_1)(x+y_2)...(x+y_n) + B(x+z_1)(x+z_2)...(x+z_k) = f(x) $$

where $y_i,z_i$ are fractions and $0<k<n$ is an integer.

In particular the cases when $k = 1,2,n$.

Also the similar equation

$$ A(x+w_1)(x+w_2)...(x+w_n) + C = f(x) $$

where $w_n$ are fractions and $C$ is a nonzero integer.

Already for small $n$ and small $A,B$ i got stuck trying to solve those.

Does vieta jumping help here ?

Is this a hard problem or an easy one ?

When do we have solutions ? Can we classify when we have solutions ?

Is this rather algebra or rather number theory ?

Can we parametrise the solutions for $n<5$ ?

---

EDIT:

For the case of the second type equation notice that if $C$ is an integer there are only finitely many possibilities for it. There exist upper bounds and lower bounds for $C$ due to the shape of the polynomial.
We can combine that idea by considering all potential $C$ with the rational root test and factoring to make a list of all candidates $w_i$.

Therefore we have made a method to solve it because we made it computable, however this is very inefficient ofcourse.

The harder question of rational $C$ comes to mind. Maybe it reduces too. Probably.

The main question (equation 1) does not seem aided by this though.

Just some comments...

Comment: Is this an example $27*(x+y)^5*(y-x)+x^3*(3*x+5*y)^2*(3*x+2*y)=y^3*(5*x+3*y)^2*(2*x+3*y)$ with $A,B=27,1$?

Comment: @Rolandb Yes that is an example. The RHS does not need to be given in factored form. Also the RHS does not need to be given with a parameter $y$. But yeah this is a solutions assuming the RHS was given and the LHS was computed.